# Instagram API / Submission Review / Issue with Video Screencast shared on public network

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

We would like to use the Instagram API to harvest comments from a Brand page into a CRM Solution.

From this CRM Solution, agents will consult and possibly reply to Instagram Posts.

I think the most appropriate use case for what we plan to do is this one:

"My product helps brands and advertisers understand, manage their audience and media rights"

Here my question:

During the submission review, we need to join a Video Screencast of our project.

This part is really annoying for us as:

We don't want to share on a public platform (like youtube) the details of our project and CRM solution

Is there any workaround to this ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to "join" video screencast, you need to submit a video of product functionality (use quicktime screen record), upload the video on google drive and share the link, only instagram will be seeing it, only the people u send link will be able to get to the video, it will not be public when sharing from Google Drive, there are varrious settings while sharing. You need to show login flow and all API functionality of app. This worked for me. The usecase looks correct for your app.